# Why does After Effects not export with audio?

Tags: after-effects, audio

I have made a simple four second long video in After Effects and exported it only to find that it had no audio. I tried changing the file type to [.MOV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format) and re-rendered it but  now the file had audio but no video. I have thoroughly researched the problem but nothing worked. here are some pictures:
[image: After Effects Project]

[image: Render settings]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: how are you playing the file?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 movie player which is what it opens with automatically.

Comment: Maybe the codec isn't installed. render with H264 under 'Format Options' in the Video Output settings.

Comment: plays sound but doesn't show video ) :

Comment: Try with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems with your playback of the rendered file. Try playing it with QuickTime (you are exporting with QuickTime after all) or VLC Media Player or Media Player Classic. All these are good options if you want to test you rendered files.

Using the media player that comes with your version of Windows is always a bad idea, Microsoft never bothered with good codec support.

Comment: Yes this works! Thank You! Now what would i do if i wanted it to play online in some sort of website?How would i play it on my I Phone? would I need to convert it to a file type that is more compatible?

Comment: See these questions f.e.:
http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/what-is-the-most-compatible-compression-codec-to-in-handbrake-use-for-video-that

http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/how-to-encode-a-video-for-the-iphone-with-handbrake

You can use your exported QuickTime Animation video source and open it in Handbrake or use Adobe Media Encoder.